# Angular 7 js2xmlparser TypeError: handler is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, xml-parsing

I am using [js2xmlparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2xmlparser) to convert an object into xml. Everything works fine in Angular8, but when i use the same code in Angular7 it throws an error 'TypeError: handler is not a function'. Provided a sample code below.

```
let js2xml = require('js2xmlparser');
let obj = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "dateOfBirth": new Date(1964, 7, 26),
  "address": {
    "@": {
      "type": "home"
    },
    "streetAddress": "3212 22nd St",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "state": "Illinois",
    "zip": 10000
  }
};
console.log(js2xml.parse("person", obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

> 1. Install https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2xmlparser
> 2. Install https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node
> 3. import * as js2xmlparser from 'js2xmlparser';
> 4. Add ref of js2xmlparser to scripts in **angular.json**

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "output": "./assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/js2xmlparser/dist/js2xmlparser.min.js"
            ]
          }
```

> 5. Changed code to:

```
let obj = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "dateOfBirth": new Date(1964, 7, 26),
  "address": {
    "@": {
      "type": "home"
    },
    "streetAddress": "3212 22nd St",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "state": "Illinois",
    "zip": 10000
  }
};
console.log(js2xmlparser.parse("person", obj));
```

> Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<person>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    <dateOfBirth>Wed Aug 26 1964 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)</dateOfBirth>
    <address type='home'>
        <streetAddress>3212 22nd St</streetAddress>
        <city>Chicago</city>
        <state>Illinois</state>
        <zip>10000</zip>
    </address>
</person>
```

> Working sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nf8k31-3nb6jh?file=app%2Fmodal-component.module.ts

Comment: Hi, thank you for quick response. I tried your steps but still getting the same error.

Comment: I added Step 4.. you maybe missing this